# Immersion of tangent bundle in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider an open set $W\subset \mathbb R^d$ and a $C^\infty$ class function $f:W\to \mathbb R^{d-c}$. If $r$ is a regular value, $Z:=f^{-1} (r)$ is a $c$-dimensional submanifold of $W$, since $$\varphi_i:x\in U_i\subset W\mapsto (x_1,\dots , x_c, f_1 (x),\dots, f_{d-c} (x) )\in \mathbb R^d$$ induces a local chart for every  $x $ in $W$, and this chart is adapted to $Z $. I don't understand how to formally obtain that the immersion of $TZ$ is the kernel of $df$: my idea would be to apply a change of coordinates, but calculating the basis change matrix  (from the coordinates induced by the $\varphi$ to the standard coordinates) implies calculating $\frac {\partial x_j} {\partial f_k}$ for every $1\le j\le d$ and $1\le k\le d-c$. Such derivations doesn't have much sense in my opinion however. Can you clarify my ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know these are charts on $W$? Doesn't it depend on which part of the derivative matrix of $f$ gives you maximal rank?

Comment: Yes @TedShifrin you're right, the choice of the first $c$ components of the $\varphi_i$ is not necessary the same for different $i$. However my problem is local (I want to find the immersion of $T_pZ $ for a generic $p\in Z $), so we can just consider a chart $\varphi_{i_0}$. Maybe we have to rearrange the standard coordinates $x_1,\dots, x_d$, but since $r$ was a regular value we know that there are $d-c$ linearly independent columns in the jacobian matrix of $f$ in $p $, corresponding to (without loss of generality) $x_{c+1},\dots , x_d$; so $\varphi_{i_0}$ is always a chart of that type.

Answer (score 1):

It's far easier than you're making it. Show (using curves, for example, or a parametrization) that $T_x Z\subset \ker df_x$, and then use dimension to finish things off.